# Arduino; How to stop listening to button press in loop while in specific function?

Tags: arduino

For a project I'm trying to get out of the Arduino loop() function and 'loop' in another function. I'm trying to make a sort of menu where the user can loop through and press an OK-button to confirm.
My setup is as follows;

Up button, OK button, Down button, set temperature button

Whenever the user pushes the temperature button, I'd like to give the user 2 options (using a LCD); change the minimum or the maximum temperature. I'd like to cycle through these options using the up and down button and give the user the option to confirm either of these temperature changes with the OK button. For some reason the Arduino doesn't listen to any button presses after I press the temperature button anymore. See code example below.

```
const int UpButton = 3;
const int OKButton = 4;
const int DownButton = 5;
const int ChangeTemperatureButton = 6;

void setup() {
  pinMode(UpButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(OKButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DownButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ChangeTemperatureButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (!digitalRead(ChangeTemperatureButton)) {
    changeTemperature();
  }
  if (!digitalRead(OKButton)) {
    // set LCD to 'not good'
  }
}

void changeTemperature() {
  // set LCD to 'Changing temperature'
  if (!digitalRead(OKButton)) {
    // set LCD to 'Set max temperature'
  }
}
```

Whenever I press the button to change the temperature it does set the LCD to 'Changing temperature'. After that I press the OK button and instead of it changing to 'Set max temperature' it changes to 'not good', which is in the loop. I think I fundamentally understand something wrong here, can anyone help me out with this one?

TL;DR: I'm trying to get and stay out of the loop when I press a certain button so my button can do something else than is defined in the loop. After everything in the changeTemperature function is set and done, I'd like to return to the loop function.

Comment: Your TLDR section is the exact opposite of typical and well-proven embedded software design.  Study state machines or FSMs.

Comment: Read [Using finite state machine](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/gusgonnet/using-finite-state-machines-fdba04)  and [Let's learn how to use Infinite State Machine](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/tolentinocotesta/let-s-learn-how-to-use-finite-state-machine-with-arduino-c524ac).

Answer (score 0):

When you press the ChangeTemperatureButton, and your program enters the changeTemperature() function, it immediately sets the LCD to 'Changing temperature' as you said.

The next thing it does is evaluate the condition of the if statement.

`if (!digitalRead(OKButton)) {`

If the condition of an if statement is false, then it is skipped over.

So if you are not simultaneously holding down the OKButton when you press the ChangeTemperatureButton, then that code will be skipped, and hence you are not seeing the 'Set max temperature' on your LCD.

I think I see though what you after, which is basically having a sub-menu, which is a very common feature of menus in general.

You might consider looking at some example code for LCD menus that use submenus to get an idea of how to implement your code.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten a good suggestion from YouJeng. To expand on that answer...

In your loop you'll do your initial button detection and debouncing work. Once the user presses the ChangeTemperatureButton your loop should call another function say "changeTemp()". You'll keep yourself in this function until you hit "OK".

There are tons of ways to accomplish this, but here's some simple pseudo-code:

```
void loop() {
   //Draw your main menu buttons

   //Handle button presses
   if(ChangeTemperatureButton) {
    changeTemp()
   }

   //Anything else your sketch needs to do
}

void changeTemp() {
  bool okPressed = false;
  //Display your text for the buttons in this mode
  //Increase, decrease, OK (for example)

  if(increase) {
   //do something
  }

  if(decrease) {
   //do something
  }

  if(OK) {
   okPressed = true;
  }

  if(!okPressed) { //This essentially keeps you in this mode until you hit the OK button
   changeTemp();
  }
}
```

There are certainly cleaner ways to do this, but this is exactly how I've done it on other projects and it works great for a quick prototype.